# How to delete a "(" from string in a list.toString()

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a string of a list in a Text that don't add the parentheses "(string)" to de string

I tried to add this: .replaceAll(RegExp('('), "")  but nothing

```
Text(
roupList.groupListName
.map((n) => '$n'.replaceAll(RegExp('('), ""))
.toString(),
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
),
```

what i get now is "(mystring,mystring,mystring)"

what i would like no parentheses "mystring,mystring,mystring"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is is easier than that:

```
String s = myList.map((listElement) => listElement.myStringProperty).join(",");
```

If you already have a list of Strings you could even do:

```
String s = myList.join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

String replace method does work. I don't know dart syntax but traverse in list with for,foreach etc and change it like below or you can use join.

```
String str1 = "Hello World"; 
str1=("New String: ${str1.replaceAll('World','ALL')}");
```

Answer (score 0):

It was close but not what i wanted , finally found that the problem was this as ( is special character i need to add \

so i done this and it works

```
Text(   
groupList.groupListName
              .map((n) => '$n')
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(RegExp(r'\)'), '')
              .replaceAll(RegExp(r'\('), ''),
```